# Why am i not continuously receiving com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED notifications?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have implemented Android In-App purchase based off of the Dungeons example. The dungeons example however did not cater for applications that required communication with a remote server before content could be delivered. I edited the code to allow this.

The [Developer Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html) has this to say about remote server content delivery

> Keep in mind, you must send a confirmation when you receive transaction information from Android Market (step 8 in figure 2). **If you don't send a confirmation message, Android Market will continue sending IN_APP_NOTIFY messages** for the transactions you have not confirmed. As a best practice, you should not send a CONFIRM_NOTIFICATIONS request for a purchased item until you have delivered the item to the user. This way, if your application crashes or something else prevents your application from delivering the product, your application will still receive an IN_APP_NOTIFY broadcast intent from Android Market indicating that you need to deliver the product. Also, as a best practice, your application must be able to handle IN_APP_NOTIFY messages that contain multiple orders.

My Implementation follows this and does not send a CONFIRM_NOTIFICATION until i am happy that my server has unlocked the content. However I have noticed that if i do not send hte CONFIRM_NOTIFICATION (this could be possible if the network drops or my server is down)then i do not continue to receive IN_APP_NOTIFY intents as stated in the documentation.

Has anyone experienced this before? Is there any solution? are the docs not up-to date?